# Google analytics show real time screen as not set for users from android

Tags: android, google-analytics

I'm using Google analytics and I notices that some of my active screens names are (not set) while watching real time report (see image)

[image]

The Google analytics configuration is set to automatically collect activity information.

Anyone have a clue why it happen or how can I debug this?

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Are you logging to GA directly via the SDK? I ask because I only noticed this when logging screen views to GA via GTM. The screen views are eventually reported correctly - like you, this is only seen under Real Time reporting

Comment: I answer the question

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @SandroSimas yes, check my answer

Answer (score 5):

The problem was that I sent events via broadcast receiver that was receiving push in the background. The events were count as a new session (thus appearing as a user in real time) and because the session wasn't related to any activity the name as "Not set".

The solution that I did is to create a new property in Google Analytics and using different tracker for these events.